# load more files on mouse scroll down in JS in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am using below JS to load more records from JS array

```
onScroll(event) {
    let increaseStartValue = 1000;

    if (event.target.scrollTop > startValue && fetchData) {
        fetchData = false;
        this.showInnerSpinner = true;
        startValue += increaseStartValue;

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.displayLineItemData();
        }, 100);
    }
}


displayLineItemData() {
    sliceFurther += 20;
    if (sliceFurther > this.totalPageSize) {
        sliceFurther = this.totalPageSize;
    }
    this.cachedLineItemData = lineItemData.slice(0, sliceFurther);
    this.showInnerSpinner = false;
    this.showSpinner = false;
    this.showImportExport = false;
    this.currentPageSize = this.cachedLineItemData.length;
    fetchData = true;
}
```

the problem with above structure is `event.target.scrollTop` is not always same with different screen sizes I get different values and also I have seen different values in different sandboxes so in the nutshell lazy loading is not stable if I check  `event.target.scrollTop` value to load more contents in JS, can anyone please suggest a better approach to check if user has scrolled at the bottom so I will call my JS method to load more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the difference by way of scrollHeight and offsetHeight:

```
if(event.target.scrollTop > event.target.scrollHeight - (event.target.offsetHeight * 2)) {
```

Here, when we move within one offsetHeight away from the end of the element (hence the * 2), we start loading more data.

Comment: Thank you Brain, this one is working perfectly without * 2 if I use * 2 then it loads records when scroll bar is in the middle.